# Do the old kernel versions get deleted from the system without letting me know?

Tags: 20.04, kernel

When I boot into 5.8.0-49-generic or 5.8.0-50-generic, my system literally breaks (my WiFi, touch pad, Ethernet, speakers, screen brightness adjustment, and Bluetooth don't work).

So, since then, I always boot into 5.8.0-48-generic, until a kernel release that doesn't cause bugs for my laptop.

Today, I thought that does Ubuntu automatically uninstall older kernels? So someday when I turn on the laptop, I see that there's no -48 kernel and it causes problems for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Ubuntu does not delete old kernels automatically. That's something the user has to do manually.

Comment: If you use `BleachBit` or, run `sudo apt autoremove` then it might remove older unused kernels.